# How to typeset dimensions of a box?

Tags: siunitx, dimensions

I want to typeset something like this: **3.0 × 3.0 × 0.9 mm**

How can I do that in LaTeX (using `siunitx` package)?

So far, I have this:

```
\num{3.0} × \num{3.0} × \SI{0.9}{\milli\metre}
```

But probably someone else knows a better solution.

Comment: I'd use `\SI{2x3x4}{\milli\metre}` to avoid confusion

Comment: Shouldn't it be `3 x 3 x 0.9 mm^3`, since the expression describes a volume, not a length?

Comment: @Jake, strictly speaking, you are right. But in this context I was only interested in the length dimensions of a box, and not its volume.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
\SI[product-units = single]{2 x 3 x 4}{\milli\metre}
```

[image]

From section *5.13 Numbers with units* of the [manual](http://ctan.altspu.ru/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf).

Comment: You can also move that to your preamble, by giving `\sisetup{product-units = single}`, so you don't have to give the option every time.

Comment: And don't forget you can write `\SI[product-units=power]{2 x 3 x 4}{\milli\metre}` if you are interested in the volume (I know you aren't).

Comment: For those reading this answer in 2022 (or later), note that this command has been replaced by ``\qtyproduct{1280x1056}`` in siunitx version 3.