# How to typeset the size of multidimensional objects using siunitx?

Tags: siunitx

What I want to write is

```
The square has a size of \SI{3 \times 4}{\cm\squared}.
```

However, it does not compile. These may be alternatives, but it's not semantically correct since an area is not determined by a range

```
The square has a size of \SIrange[range-phrase=$\times$,range-units=single]{3}{4}{\cm\squared}.
```

nor a list:

```
The square has a size of \SIlist[list-pair-separator=$\times$,list-units=single]{3;4}{\cm\squared}.
```

At least the last option generalizes nicely:

```
The cube has a size of \SIlist[list-separator=$\times$,list-final-separator=$\times$,list-units=single]{3;4;5}{\cm\cubed}.
```

Is there a semantically correct way of doing this that I have missed in the manual?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    % The square has a size of \SI{3 \times 4}{\cm\squared}.

    The square has a size of \SIrange[range-phrase=$\times$,range-units=single]{3}{4}{\cm\squared}.

    The square has a size of \SIlist[list-pair-separator=$\times$,list-units=single]{3;4}{\cm\squared}.

    The cube has a size of \SIlist[list-separator=$\times$,list-final-separator=$\times$,list-units=single]{3;4;5}{\cm\cubed}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\SI[product-units=single]{3 x 4}{\cm\squared}.`? [How to typeset dimensions of a box?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32956)

Comment: By the way, I think `\SI[product-units=power]{3 x 4}{\cm}` is even more semantically correct.